# Google Slides API pages.get()

Tags: php, google-slides-api

I'm currently trying the Slides Google API and I've done the quick start guide so I could understand how this works (I have to say I'm not a expert developer).

After trying different things, I have reached a problem. 
I have a presentation on my Google Drive which I want to try things on.
So far I've made that the code on the quick start guide works on a server, not in command line like it's showed.

Now I want to try new things but there is a problem with something.

And the code is

`$slidesService = new Google_Service_Slides($client);
 $presentations = $slidesService->presentations;
$pages = $slidesService->pages;`

The error is:

Undefined property: Google_Service_Slides_Resource_Presentations::$pages

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [generated source](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Slides.php#L102) of the Slides PHP client, I think you want `$slidesService->presentations_pages`.

Comment: Thanks dude! Solved my issue.